# How to identify first call in Cordova

Tags: javascript, cordova, dom-events

I have a cordova-based app that runs on Android, iOS and Windows Phone. The starting point in my app is the index.html page, which will not only be loaded on app start, but you can redirect to it from inside the app.

I want to execute some code if and only if the app was just started (so when the index.html was displayed the first time) and not if it was redirected to it. I tried to use cookies that expire when the session ends, but cordova does not work with cookies.

Also I do not want to use session storage because some older Androids (as well as Internet Explorer) cannot handle this.

My used cordova version is 4.0.0

**EDIT:**

I forgot to mention that it is not a single-page app, but I use multiple pages that can be accessed, so the deviceready-event does not work, because it would be fired every time I access the index.html-page

Comment: When the user is redirected to index.html, does that load a new instance of index.html or is it simply returning to the instance loaded on app start?

Comment: either you can use localstorage or sqlite database to store some value and check if the app has started or not in this scnerio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try smth like this:

```
function documentReady() {
   document.addEventListener("deviceready", handleDeviceReady, false);
}
 
function handleDeviceReady(event) {
   //cordova api is ready for use
   if (!localStorage.getItem('alreadyStarted')) {
       // App just started!
       localStorage.setItem('alreadyStarted', true);
   }
}
```

**UPD.** Also you need to set the flag at first startup (i.e. `alreadyStarted = true` in sessions or LocalStorage) and check it in `handleDeviceReady()` later.

Comment: Deviceready is triggered every time I get to the page, not only the first time

Comment: @puchmu see **UPD** section

Comment: @puchmu sorry. But LocalStorage aka "Web Storage" [supports](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/features/storage) Android 2.1+ and IE8+

Comment: Thanks, I could not find another solution myself, so I will accept your answer

Comment: If you could not find your solution then you shouldn't accepted it. I was first confused when I saw it at first glance.

Answer (score 0):

Write to the database at first run. Everytime the app starts, check the database to see if that string is present. If it it, ignore. Else, create and write.